# In constructing a Google Form dropdown is it possible for the response that gets stored to be a coded value of what the user chooses?

Tags: google-apps-script, dropdown, google-forms

In my Google Form I want to show the user a dropdown list consisting of several values from which he can choose one value. Such as:

Guernsey

Hereford

Jersey

But when his response gets stored into the response sheet I want it to be stored as a corresponding *coded* value, such as:

301

371

422

Is there any way to do this when I build a Form?  Can it be accomplished with Google App Script?

Comment: Insert a helper column and use `replace()` or `vlookup()` / `index(match())` would be the most straight forward if you don't know App Script.

Answer (score 0):

Google Forms doesn't include form responses codification and the built-in feature that send form responses to an spreadsheet either. One alternative is that you use on form summit installable trigger. There are one for scripts bounded to forms and another for scripts bounded to spreasheet, each one having their own event object. For details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events.